# How to open variable file in specific folder in python?

Tags: python, file, directory

I'm new to python and working on a way to open a file named acne.txt which is inside my define folder in the same python34 folder as my code.

The code I've written for the same is:

```
NN_is = [word for word,pos in tagged_sent if pos == 'NN']
print(NN_is[0])
searchfile = open(r"define/NN_is[0].txt", "r")
file_contents = searchfile.readlines()
searchfile.close()
```

The variable NN_is[0] when printed yields acne. Can someone help me in solving this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to concatenate the directory and file name, and use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.format#str.format) to construct the string for the file name:

```
import os.path

path = os.path.join('define', '{}.txt'.format(NN_is[0]))
with open(path) as searchfile:
    file_contents = searchfile.readlines()
    ...
```

I also recommend that you open the file within a `with` statement. This ensures that the file will always be closed, even if there is an error. It's also handy because you don't need to explicitly close the file - it will be closed when the `with` statement goes out of scope.

Comment: Maybe to add a bit which was wrong with the code: `""define/NN_is[0].txt"` is a string with the **content** `NN_is[0]` whereas `NN_is` (without quotationmarks) is the variable `NN_is`. You can combine a string and the content of the variable: `"define/" + NN_is[0]` is a string whith `define/` and the content of the variable concatenated. `os.path.join` and `str.format` only makes stuff easier (os.path.join will automatically use the right "/" or "//" or whatever your OS uses) but is not "needed" strictly speaking.

Comment: Suppose there is no file with the name in the variable NN_is[0], and I wish to print that "No such file exists". What should I add to do the above task?

Comment: @NamanArora: well, what happens when you try to open a non-existent file? An exception is raised: `FileNotFoundError` in Python 3, or `IOError` in Python 2. So you can use a `try/except` statement to catch and handle the exception.